# Run installer minimized + NotifyIcon

Tags: nsis

I have my command line options that work for my installer, which involves the plugin NotifyIcon. Because of this plugin, I can not run my installer silently through the command line. It has one custom page MUI page over. Two questions occured to me, so if anyone can help, please do so.

1. I'm using MUI, so I know I have to use a separate function and then define `MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit !` I load the code correctly and icon works for me properly.
2. Running the installation mínimimizado. I've dealt with "HideWindow" on . MyGuiInit OnInit and also in my own functions, and anywhere else I could think of, but that does not work very well. What I need is that the first boot installation window minimized and the icon appears on the task bar (this already works for me) and when you press the icon on the taskbar window is restored installation to continue with the installation normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand your question but if you want to start the installer minimized you can do:

```
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_GUIINIT myGuiInit
Function myGuiInit
System::Call 'USER32::PostMessage(i$hwndparent,i0x0112,i0xF020,i0)'
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It was exactly what I needed, start the installation minimized. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had a similar problem. Calling HideWindow from onGUIInit (or before the first call to nsdialogs::show) doesn't seem to work. Running my program minimized is a good workaround for me.

Comment: @FranciscoR: Why not make it a silent installer?

Comment: @Anders: Because it's an updater that runs automatically. In case an update is available it shows a page but I don't like it annoys the user. Maybe I should use NotifyIcon too.